SAP Hybris customerReview - advanced-search for product code
Is it possible that in backoffice to add a new field in the customerReview advanced-search, to search for customer reviews by the product code, ootb i can search by the product itself:
-<context merge-by="type" parent="GenericItem" type="CustomerReview" component="advanced-search">
   <advanced-search:advanced-search xmlns:advancedsearch="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/advancedsearch">
        <advanced-search:field-list>
-<advanced-search:field xmlns="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/advancedsearch" name="product" selected="true"/>
-</advanced-search:field-list>
 </advanced-search:advanced-search>
    </context>

I tried this but it didn't work:
-<context merge-by="type" type="CustomerReview" component="advanced-search">
    <advanced-search:advanced-search>
        <advanced-search:field-list>
            <advanced-search:field name="product.code" selected="true"/>
-</advanced-search:field-list>
   </advanced-search:advanced-search>
</context>

